i have single update service i need to make as multiple update service using node js
I have node js service code it take single task number to update url, i have modified the code for multiple task number to update,in single api call i need to update multiple task number but its not happening in below code.
const updateRFC = async (request, response) => {
  const { CONTENT_TYPE, ITSM_CONST } = constants;
  const { APIGEE_HOST } = ITSM_CONST;
  const correlationId = request.headers['x-correlation-id'];
  logger.trace('operations-util :: itsm-tool :: changes :: standardChangeRequest :: createStandardRFC :: Method Entry', correlationId);

  const jasonBody = request.body.metaInformation.ctaskdetails;
  console.log("sowmya", jasonBody);


  const rfcOptions = () => jasonBody.map(async (task) => {
    // request.body.metaInformation.ctaskdetails = envt;
    // console.log("envt",envt);
    // const body = JSON.stringify(request.body.metaInformation.ctaskdetails);
    // console.log("bodyjson", body);

    const host = CONFIG.application.EPAAS_ENV.toLowerCase().includes('e3') ? CONFIG.application.url['apigee-api-request-host'] : APIGEE_HOST;
    const path = '/management/operations/v2/itsm/change_mgmt/changes/tasks/state';
    const port = CONFIG.application.url['apigee-api-request-port'];
    const method = 'PUT';
  
    const hmacOptions = {
      clientKey: '',
      clientSecret: '',
      host,
      path,
      method,
      port,
    };

    const hmacAuthToken = hmacAuth.generateAuthHeader(hmacOptions, JSON.stringify(task), correlationId);
    const options = {
      host,
      path,
      method,
      headers: {
        correlation_id: correlationId,
        'content-type': CONTENT_TYPE,
        'X-AMEX-API-KEY': hmacOptions.clientKey,
        Authorization: hmacAuthToken,
        service_id: CONFIG.application.VAULT.ITSM_SRE_API_SERVICE_ID,
      },
    };

    console.log("sowmya1", options);
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
    const result = await PromiseUtil.post(options, JSON.stringify(task));
    console.log("result", result);
    return result;
  });

     // const multiServiceEDCResult = await Promise.allSettled(rfcOptions())
    // console.log("multiServiceEDCResult", multiServiceEDCResult);
  await Promise.allSettled(rfcOptions())
  .then((result) => {
    response.status(200).send(result);
    console.log("resultresp",result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    logger.warn(`operations-util :: itsm-tool :: changes :: standardChangeRequest :: createStandardRFC :: ${error.toString()}`, correlationId);
    response.status(500).send({ status: 500, message: error.toString() });
    logger.trace('operations-util :: canary-control :: manage :: globalTrafficFetch :: Method Exit', correlationId);
  });
};

I have node js service code it take single task number to update url, i have modified the code for multiple task number to update,in single api call i need to update multiple task number but its not happening in below code.
I am expecting to update multiple taskNumber using single api call.

try this: const rfcOptions = () => jasonBody.map(task => {   ...   ...   const result = PromiseUtil.post(options, JSON.stringify(task));   return result })
you need array of promises for Promise.allsettled()

how can i update it at once for example if i have 6 task number to update at once how can achieve  it from this above code its not happening.

this url is for single update not for multiple update i have to modified it its getting updated but not at a. time i need to update 6 or more or multiple task number at a time
